# how to make approximate version of this scrollable list of tiles from db?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

[audible on smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqtyY.jpg)

i like how audible does this
my device logs in
it downloads my list of titles from a db
and displays them in neat tidy uniform tiles (scrollable)
upon tapping a tile, i'm taken to that title and other options from there

i'd like to add something similar to my app.
it would be a list of parts for certain pc builds
each tile would have small image, and brief description

trying to do this using **xamarin forms**.

are the tiles really XAML buttons?
do not want to hard-code each tile, they should change as the data in the db changes. what practice is needed to do this?
i know i'm new, sorry.
i've been going through docs, but can't seem to find what i *think* i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you haven't really asked anything so it is hard to answer you specifically so here is the general idea of what you should do and search the docs for.

You need to use a `listview` with a custom `viewcell` whose elements are bound to the results of a query to your database. Then bind a command that navigates to a details page when a row of your listview is tapped.